# JXBrowser Licensing issue

Tags: jxbrowser

From today morning I am getting an error of License failure for jxbrowser 6.x. However the license says **Expiration date: NEVER**. Then why are we getting this error?

Below is the details of the license..

```
Product: JxBrowser
Version: 6.x
Licensed to: 
License type: Development
License info: Single-user license
Expiration date: NEVER
Support expiration date: 19-08-2016
Generation date: 04-01-2016
Platforms: win32/x64;linux/x86;mac/x64;linux/x64;mac/x86;win32/x86;mac/ppc
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with license checking that was fixed in version 6.1. I recommend that you download the latest version of JxBrowser and update it in your application. It will help to resolve this issue and successfully use JxBrowser further.

Comment: 6.14 also doesn't seem to respect the license file.